# What is the Text Blocks (or Multiline Strings) feature in Java?

Tags: java, java-15, java-text-blocks

Java SE 13 introduced *[Text Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/text_blocks/index.html)* (or Multiline Strings) feature. What are its differences and the similarities with the existing string representation?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404681/8967612). (**Moderator Note:** If you have an opinion on its acceptability, do not post a comment here. Instead, post an *answer* to the linked Meta question. Meta-commentary here is subject to being deleted.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### What is a text block?

A [text block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) is a multi-line string literal and the feature offers a clean way to format the string in a predictable way, without using most of the escape sequences. It starts and ends with a `"""` (three double-quotes marks) e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = """
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Hello World</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        Java rocks!
                    </body>
                </html>""";

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Java rocks!
    </body>
</html>
```

With the traditional string representation, the code would look like

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "<html>\n"
                + " <head>\n"
                + "     <title>Hello World</title>\n"
                + " </head>\n"
                + " <body>\n"
                + "     Java rocks!\n"
                + " </body>\n"
                + "</html>";

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Another ***key difference*** is that a text block begins with **three double-quote characters followed by a line terminator** which is not the case with the traditional string representation. It means

1. The text block can not be put on a single line.
2. The content of the text block can not follow the three opening double quotes on the same line.

   ```
   String str = "Hello World!"; // The traditional string

   String textBlock = """
           Hello World!
           """; // The text block

   String notAllowed = """Hello World!"""; // Error

   // The following code will fail compilation
   String notAllowed2 ="""Hello
            World!
           """;
   ```

This was a much-needed feature in Java.

**A note about how it compares with text block in Kotlin (a modern JVM-based language):**

- Kotlin does not have any of the two above-mentioned constraints.
- Kotlin does not require escaping a `\` inside the text block which makes writing a RegEx expression easier e.g. the following is a valid text block in Kotlin but invalid in Java:

```
    var str = """
        \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}
        """
```

In Java, one will have to write it as

```
var str = """
    \\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}
    """;
```

**A note about indentation:**

The compiler shifts the complete text block to the left and then retains the specified spacing.

```
String str1 = """
           Hello
        """;
        ^^^<-----The three whitespace characters before Hello will be retained
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Text block without a line break at the end
        String str1 = """
                Hello""";

        // Text block with a line break at the end
        String str2 = """
                Hello
                """;

        // Text block with three whitespaces in the beginning and a line break at the end
        String str3 = """
                   World!
                """;
        System.out.println(str1);
        System.out.println(str2);
        System.out.println(str3);
        System.out.println("Java rocks!");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello
Hello

   World!

Java rocks!
```

### Is it available only as a Preview Feature?

It remained available in Java SE 13 and Java SE 14 as a *Preview Feature* and has been standardised with Java SE 15. With Java SE 13 and 14, like any *Preview Feature*, it has to be compiled and executed with `--enable-preview` option e.g.

**To compile:**

```
javac --enable-preview --release 13 Main.java
```

**To execute:**

```
java --enable-preview Main
```

### Are they stored in the String Pool?

Yes, they are. The *text blocks* are compiled to the same type as that of the traditional `String` value i.e. the byte code does not distinguish between a traditional `String` value and a *text block*.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "Hello World!";
        String str2 = """
                Hello World!""";
        System.out.println(str1 == str2);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

### Can a *text block* be concatenated with another string?

Yes, a text block can be concatenated to a traditional string value or another *text block* in the same way, the traditional `String` values are concatenated. As already described above, the byte code does not distinguish between a traditional `String` value and *text block*.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str1 = "Hello ";
        String str2 = """
                World!""";
        String str3 = """
                 Java rocks!
                """;
        System.out.println(str1 + str2);
        System.out.println(str1 + (str2 + str3));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Hello World!
Hello World! Java rocks!
```

Note that I have put whitespace after `Hello` in `str1` and another whitespace before `Java rocks!` in `str3`.

### Does it support *Escape Sequences*?

Yes, the escape sequences will be evaluated in the traditional way e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = """
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Hello World</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        Java\n\t\trocks!
                    </body>
                </html>""";

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Java
        rocks!
    </body>
</html>
```

### Does it support replaceable parameters?

Yes, you can replace a parameter in the text block using `%s` or `$<<replaceable-parameter>>` as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = """
                What is the distance between %s and %s?""";

        System.out.println(String.format(text, "earth", "moon"));
        System.out.println(String.format(text, "earth", "mercury"));

        // Alternative-1
        text = """
                What is the distance between $celestial1 and $celestial2?""";

        System.out.println(text.replace("$celestial1", "earth").replace("$celestial2", "moon"));

        // Alternative-2 using the deprecated String#formatted
        text = """
                What is the distance between %s and %s?""";
        System.out.println(text.formatted("earth", "moon"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
What is the distance between earth and moon?
What is the distance between earth and mercury?
What is the distance between earth and moon?
What is the distance between earth and moon?
```