# What is the correct regex for extracting some part of string from string

Tags: java, regex

```
    String query = "Select Count(distinct c.requestId)  FROM Abc1Value c  WHERE 1=1 and c.templateName is NULL "
            +" AND (c.quickStatus IS NULL OR c.quickStatus = 'S') "
            + " AND (c.sCode='MYCODE'  OR exists (SELECT b.dseaReqId FROM drstSShareValue b WHERE b.dseaReqId=c.requestId and b.sCode='MYCODE'))  "
            + " AND  (upper(c.licenseNo) like '%"12548"%' or upper(c.docLicenseNo) like '%""%' or upper(c.uncontrolledLicense) like '%""%' or upper(c.nonAuthNo) like '%""%' or upper(c.reAuthNo) like '%""%') "
            + " and  upper(c.grantedByCtryCode) like '%US%' ";
```

I want to extract all "like string" i.e.

1. like '%"12548"%'
2. like '%""%'
3. like '%""%'
4. like '%""%'
5. like '%""%'

I am using regex in java `(?i)(\\s)+like(\\s)*('%\")(.+?)(\"%')` when i get the group it does not return correct result.
Please suggest.

Comment: Try `"(?i)\\s+like\\s+'%\".*?\"%'"`.

Comment: The java code in your question does not compile. If you **really** need the embedded double quote characters (`"`), then you must escape them like so: `\"` However I don't think you need them so you can simply remove them.

Comment: _I want to extract all "like string"_ Does that mean you also want to extract `like '%US%'`? You didn't include that in your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex, `(?i)like\s+'%.*?%'` which means:

- `(?i)` matches the remainder of the pattern in a case-insensitive manner e.g. it enables matching all of the following words: `like`, `LIKE`, `Like` etc.
- `\s+` matches whitespace characters [one or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) times.
- `.*?` matches lazily, any character any number of times.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String query = """
                Select Count(distinct c.requestId)  FROM Abc1Value c  WHERE 1=1 and c.templateName is NULL
                 AND (c.quickStatus IS NULL OR c.quickStatus = 'S')
                 AND (c.sCode='MYCODE'  OR exists (SELECT b.dseaReqId FROM drstSShareValue b WHERE b.dseaReqId=c.requestId and b.sCode='MYCODE'))
                 AND  (upper(c.licenseNo) like '%"12548"%' or upper(c.docLicenseNo) like '%""%' or upper(c.uncontrolledLicense) like '%""%' or upper(c.nonAuthNo) like '%""%' or upper(c.reAuthNo) like '%""%')
                 AND  upper(c.grantedByCtryCode) like '%US%'
                """;
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?i)like\\s+'%.*?%'").matcher(query);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
like '%"12548"%'
like '%""%'
like '%""%'
like '%""%'
like '%""%'
like '%US%'
```

Additional demo: check this out at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fo9HpV/1).

**Note:** In order to keep `query` look clean, I've used the [Text Blocks (or Multiline Strings) feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65676449/10819573) standardized as part of Java SE 15. However, this is not necessary and you can write it the way you posted it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?i)(\\s)+like(\\s)*('%\")(.*?)(\"%')
```

.*? = zero or more times

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired matches, you can also use a match without any capture groups and match zero or more chars after the `'%"`

```
(?i)(?<!\S)like\s*'%".*?"%'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vXk2EH/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/rc80Rg)

In Java

```
String regex = "(?i)(?<!\\S)like\\s*'%\".*?\"%'";
```