# How to compare word within the whole string in java and increase its count?

Tags: java

I have a `String replacedtext` which is:

```
Replaced text:OPTIONS (ERRORS=5000)
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
APPEND INTO TABLE REPO.test
Fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed BY '"'
trailing nullcols
(
CODE ,
user,
date DATE "MM/DD/YYYY"
)
```

I want to count the Number of **REPO.** in this whole string.So,I tried in this way but it is not working.

```
String[] words = replacedtext.split("\\s+");
        int count=0;
       for(String w:words){​​​​​​​
           if(w.equals("\\bREPO.\\b")){​​​​​​​
               count++;
           }​​​​​​​
       }​​​​​​​
System.out.println ("count is :"+count);
```

Output coming is:

```
count is :0
```

Since in the string `REPO.` is seen for once. My output needs to be `count is:1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`w.equals("\\bREPO.\\b")` compares the content of `w` with `\\bREPO.\\b` literally and therefore you are getting a wrong result.

You can count the occurrences of `REPO` using the regex API.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String replacedText = """
                Replaced text:OPTIONS (ERRORS=5000)
                LOAD DATA
                INFILE *
                APPEND INTO TABLE REPO.test
                Fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed BY '"'
                trailing nullcols
                (
                CODE ,
                user,
                date DATE "MM/DD/YYYY"
                )
                """;

        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\bREPO\\b").matcher(replacedText);

        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

Note that `\b` is used as [word boundary matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html).

Java SE 9 onwards, you can use [`Matcher#results`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results()) to get a `Stream` on which you can call [`count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--) as shown below:

```
long count = matcher.results().count();
```

**Note:** I've used [Text Block feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65676449/10819573) to make the text block look more readable. You can form the string in the Pre-Java15 way.

Comment: `int count = (int) matcher.results().count();`

Answer (score 0):

Probably 2 issues here. `.` is a special symbol which represents `exactly one character`. So your `REPO.test` won't match.

The second issue is `equals` method. You should use `matcher` or just filter by regex and then count.

I would do it so:

```
int count = Pattern.compile("\\s").splitAsStream(replacedtext)
    .filter(Pattern.compile("\\bREPO\\b").asPredicate())
    .count()
System.out.println(count);
```