# JDBC stored procedure MariaDB syntax

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I'm a beginner of creating a stored procedure using JDBC and MariaDB. When I create the procedure, I get an error. I ran in to the problem since yesterday:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@auth_id varchar(15),@auth_fname varchar(20) output,@auth_lname varchar(20) o...' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:944)
```

What I tried so far, I attached the code below. I don't know what causes the error.

```
public class Jdbcc {
    
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    
    public Jdbcc()
    {
        Connect();
       }
    public void Connect()
    {
      try 
      {
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/abclibrary", "root","");     
       String str = "CREATE PROCEDURE authors @auth_id varchar(15), @auth_fname varchar(20) output, @auth_lname varchar(20) output AS SELECT @auth_fname=auth_fname,@auth_lname= auth_lname FROM authors where auth_id=@auth_id";

                          Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                          int k = stmt.executeUpdate(str);
                          System.out.println("Created.......");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Jdbcc jk = new Jdbcc();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the specific problem you're asking about, but the SQL you create from concatenating strings needs spaces between `auth_lname` and `FROM` and between `authors` and `where`.

Comment: so how to write it properly sir

Comment: @NisaYathu - It's much easier to preserve the format [using Java15 text block feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65676449/10819573). However, very few individuals and teams have started using Java15 yet. For a version lower than 15, the best way to avoid such problems is first, type `""` and then copy and paste the string between the double-quotes.

Comment: Assuming you are using IDEs like Eclipse or IntelliJ, your IDE will automatically break the string into multiple lines preserving the whitespace and also escaping the characters like ``\``, double quote etc.

Comment: `authors @auth_id varchar(15), @auth_fname varchar(20)...` should be inside parenthesis. Check the syntax at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-procedure/

Comment: can you write the properway it will helpful for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to create the stored procedure:

```java
       String str = "CREATE PROCEDURE authors (p_auth_id varchar(15), OUT p_auth_fname varchar(20), OUT p_auth_lname varchar(20))\n" +
                    "BEGIN\n" +
                    "  SELECT auth_fname, auth_lname INTO p_auth_fname, p_auth_lname FROM authors where auth_id = p_auth_id;\n" +
                    "END;";
```

The changes I made were as follows:

- Don't prefix procedure parameter names with `@`.  I added `p_` prefixes to parameter names so that they don't clash with column names.
- You need to surround the list of procedure parameters with parentheses `(`...`)`.
- Output parameters are identified by specifying `OUT` before the parameter name, not with `output` afterwards.
- You can't write `SELECT variable1=column1, variable2=column2, ...` as you may be able to do in other databases.  Instead write `SELECT column1, column2, ... INTO variable1, variable2, ...`.
- The body of the procedure have been wrapped in a `BEGIN` ... `END;` block.

After I made these changes, I could use your Java class to create the stored procedure, and then call it from the MariaDB console.

Incidentally, if the stored procedure already exists, you can use `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ...` instead of `CREATE PROCEDURE ...`, which will replace the existing stored procedure.

See also the [MariaDB documentation for `CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-procedure/).

Answer (score 0):

Take care about spaces:

```java
String str = "CREATE PROCEDURE authors @auth_id varchar(15), @auth_fname varchar(20) output, @auth_lname varchar(20) output "
                           +"AS "
                           +"SELECT @auth_fname=auth_fname,@auth_lname= auth_lname " //you missed space here
                           + "FROM authors " //and here
                           +"where auth_id=@auth_id";
```

`auth_lnameFROM` and `authorswhere` were the problem

Comment: i update the code please have a look still problem